# Why do I have two identical arrays when trying to separate struct stat by files and folders?

Tags: c, unix

I need to output files, sorted by creation date and folders. I went straight to separate everything in current catalogue into two arrays(one for file and one for files) and then do the stuff with them but suddenly I realized that I have two SIMILAR arrays. I need help.

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE ;
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void insertionSort(struct stat* myArray)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(struct stat); ++i)
      {
        int j = i - 1;   
        while (j >= 0 && myArray[j].st_ctime > myArray[i].st_ctime)
         { 
            myArray[j + 1].st_ctime = myArray[j].st_ctime; 
            j = j - 1; 
        } 
        myArray[j + 1].st_ctime = myArray[i].st_ctime; 
      }
}

int main()
{
  char cwd[PATH_MAX];
   if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
   {
     struct dirent *pDirent;
     DIR *pDir;
     pDir = opendir(cwd);
     if(pDir != NULL)
     {
       struct stat sb;
       struct stat* fileArray;
       struct stat* folderArray;
       fileArray = malloc(sizeof(struct stat)); 
       folderArray = malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
       int fiIndex = 0, foIndex = 0; 
      while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
      {
        if(strcmp(pDirent->d_name, ".") != 0 
        && strcmp(pDirent->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {          
          stat(pDirent->d_name,&sb); 
//I suppose that the mistake is somewhere in this switch but I'm not really so sure         
           switch (sb.st_mode & S_IFMT) 
           {
           case S_IFDIR:
           folderArray[foIndex++] = sb; 
           folderArray = realloc(folderArray, sizeof(folderArray)+sizeof(struct stat));
           break; 
           case S_IFREG: 
           fileArray[fiIndex++] = sb; 
           folderArray = realloc(fileArray, sizeof(fileArray)+sizeof(struct stat));
           break;
           }
        }      
      }  
      insertionSort(fileArray);
      insertionSort(folderArray);
       for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(fileArray)/sizeof(stat); ++i)
      {
        rewinddir(pDir);
         while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
         {
            if(strcmp(pDirent->d_name, ".") != 0 
            && strcmp(pDirent->d_name, "..") != 0)
            {
              stat(pDirent->d_name,&sb);
              if(sb.st_ino == fileArray[i].st_ino)
              {
                printf("%s\n",pDirent->d_name);
              }
            }

         }
      }
     }
     closedir(pDir);
   }
  return 0; 
}
```

And also I have a few questions like should I be using switch at all? Is there any more elegant way to compare for files or folders? The same about print, I think I made it kinda ugly :/

Comment: Remember that `sizeof` applied to a pointer gives you the size of the pointer, not the amount of stuff to which it points.  If you want the latter, you have to keep track of it yourself.

Comment: @NateEldredge I've already figured out that it wasn't working due to poor realloc as well, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`folderArray = realloc(fileArray, ...`

Surely that is not what you intended.

Comment: Okay this was an extemely dumb mistake. Thank you. Wondering how I missed that one

Comment: just an hint : in an answer try to be more verbose, else some people can ask to delete it because a simple remark must be used rather than an answer when so short (UV anyway)